# Reset slider to first slide on navigating home

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a one page scrolling website.
I am using Jassor slider with 3-4 slides auto-playing, I want to somehow make the `href="#home"` or `href="#"` which takes to top of the page where the slider is on some random autoplaying slide.

Is there any way I can reset to first slide when the page scrolls to `#home`?

Comment: Please share some html and JS telling us the way you are initializing the slider.

Comment: You can create a javascript function in which you can reset the slider and call that function when clicking on 'Top' or 'Home' link

Comment: sorry guys, i forgot to mention the site. http://blackgoldconferences.com/

Comment: hi Sac, i also think that will be a good approach, 
jassor has these tow functions:
[code]$PlayTo(slideIndex[, slideDuration])
//Play slider to position 'slideIndex' within a period calculated base on 'slideDuration'
$GoTo(slideIndex)
[/code]
but they have not provided any reference in their docs about how to use it on click event